# Time Picker issue

Tags: android, material-design, datetimepicker, timepicker

I have a question: can I somehow use `TimePicker` which would look like this one below in APIs less than 21? At least that this kind of `TimePicker` would be available for API 14 and above.[image]

Also, I've seen an app that could use `TimePicker` like this in API 16. So, it is possible but I don't know how to. I've searched internet for awhile and some people were saying that it is possible to use Material Design in APIs 7 and above by using appcompat:v7:23.1.0 dependency and AppCompat theme. But either this way does not work or I messed some things up while was doing it(setup process was quite easy so I think I didn't).

Please, help me!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the library for material date and timepicker, it supports 4.0 and higher

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.1.1'
}
```

https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker

Comment: But is it legal to produce an app with libraries from GitHub?

Comment: Yes it is, it's very normal.